# OWASP top 10 web app security risks mitigation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, owasp, hdiv

I'm using [HDIV](http://hdiv.org/) for JSF and Spring MVC applications to mitigate OWASP top 10 security risks. Now I have to implement the same in AngularJS.

Is there any library avilable similar to HDIV for AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client-mvc scenarios such as AngularJS Spring-Hateoas approach fits well with HDIV. Actually, HDIV has a module for that integration: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/tree/hdiv-hateoas

It’s not totally finished yet but the integration of URL resources works (see ResourceRequestDataValueProcessor) but it’s not finished the support for forms. When we started this module this data format for forms was not finished or defined, and that’s why we did not continue this work.

We think it could be possible a very integrated solution with HDIV following Hypermedia and HATEOAS
approach for client-mvc apps or also for native mobile apps. In other words, within REST Hypermedia approach all URLs or forms, excepting the first URL, are created in the server side, in a similar way of traditional server side MVC web technologies.

Please take a look to this module (hdiv-hateoas) and we can support you if you have any doubts.

Roberto Velasco (HDIV team)

Comment: Successful integration between HDIV and Mustache JS/AngularJS frameworks in order to cover OWASP top ten risks, see how to: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/69